# How to lookup or count the number of instance vars inside the controller of Rails3 app per request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my rails 3 app, I wanted to know/count the instance variables instantiated in controller action, helper methods in view or in ruby-debug.

The way I attempted is put a `<% debugger %>` in the view, reload the page and in the console:

```
(rdb:25) p controller.instance_variables
[:@action_has_layout, :@view_context_class, :@_headers, :@_status, :@_response, :@_request,
 :@_env, :@lookup_context, :@_action_name, :@_response_body, :@tenant, :@_config,
  :@current_user, :@current_account, :@_params, :@station, :@form, :@line, :@enabled_steps, 
  :@stations, :@raw, :@form_to_render, :@locals_hash]
(rdb:25)
```

I am pretty sure its not listing all the instance vars defined in my helper methods. And whats that `:@_...` kinda variable name? How can I access those vars?

```
(rdb:25) p controller.locals_hash
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `locals_hash' for #<FormsController:0x00000108533cd0>
(rdb:25) p locals_hash
NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `locals_hash' for #<#<Class:0x00000100c5ef08>:0x000001081fd0e8>
(rdb:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this list variables from helper. I'd say those are attached to the view and you can grab them using:

```
self.assigns.keys
```

From a debugger statement in the view.

the `@_` vars are generally private or without accessors that's why you can't access them easily. But remember Ruby doesn't forbid anything and treats you as a responsible developer so:

- for instance variables without accessors: `p controller.instance_variable_get(:@_headers)`
- for private methods: use the `send` method

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but Pry gem may be very helpful in your debugging endeavours. It allows to easily "go into" the objects using its `cd` and `ls` commands (and many more).

http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails